# How repeatable read isolation level and others are implemented in distributed/replicated databases?

Tags: replication, locking, distributed-databases, distributed-transactions, consistency

I'm studying distributed systems/DBs and I'm struggling understanding isolation levels when we talk about distributed systems.
Avoiding problems like dirty read, non-repeatable read, phantom reads, write-skew, etc. when we have a single DB is pretty straightforward with the introduction of optimistic / pessimistic concurrency control algorithms.

Nevertheless, I'm really not understanding how the same problems are avoided when we deal with distributed systems.

### Example

[image: Simple DB cluster with 3 nodes in strong consistency setup]

Let's say that we have three total nodes (*N = 3*) for our DB and we want strong consistency for some reason (*R = 2* and *W = 2*, so *R + W > N*).
Let' say now that we have two transactions: T1, T2.

- T1:

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM X WHERE X.field = 'something'

  ... DO WORK ...

  SELECT * FROM X WHERE X.field = 'something'
  ```
- T2:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO X VALUES(..,..,..)   -- impact T1 search criteria
  ```

T2 will commit while T1 is in "DO WORK" phase, so we will have a *phantom read* problem.

### Question

How is this situation handled in the illustrated system above?
Do systems like this use 2PC-like algorithm and rely on the fact that one transaction will fail in one node due to the R+W>N constraint? If yes, is it a used solution? I would say that this is complex (when we have to rollback the committed transaction in Node_X) and it is also slow probably.

Do you have any useful material that I can check to continue studying this topic? I really cannot find much about this, there is very few material that discusses isolation level in distributed systems.

Feel free to correct the above if I made a mistake.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK for MariaDB/Galera that was solved by elimination of actual concurrency. All writes to the cluster are serialized in the common (distributed) queue and applied one write at a time to all nodes. InnoDB storage has so-called `undo log` where all changes are logged for rolling back. With `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level all reads works with the "consistent snapshot". That means that reads inside R/R transaction will get not an actual data but (actual data • rollback to PiT) where PiT = Point in Time when R/R transaction has been started. The more writes occures during R/R transaction, the more writes will be "rolled back" by reads inside the said transaction. That approach has some overhead for writes tracking and rolling back but it works.